# WebGL: passing uniform arrays to shader

Tags: arrays, glsl, webgl, shader, uniform

Tried to do just like here: [Pass array to shader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17002487/pass-array-to-shader)
And like here: [Passing an array of vectors to a uniform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725424/passing-an-array-of-vectors-to-a-uniform)

But still no luck. I think I do just like there but it doesn't work:

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
shaderProgram.lightsUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "lights"); // Getting location
gl.uniform1f(shaderProgram.lightsUniform, new Float32Array([3,1,2,3,4,5])); // Let's try to send some light (currently each light is one float) as array.
```

Vertex Shader Code:

```
uniform float lights[6]; // Declaration

...

vLight *= lights[0]; // Let's try to mutliply our light by the first array item. There should be 3.0.
```

**Summary**: I send an array to shader with non-zero-floats.

**Result**: totally black! I.e. lights[0] contains 0.0 but expected 3.0. If I try lights[1], lights[2] etc. they all give the same result!

Let's now try to pass just one float. I change

```
gl.uniform1f(shaderProgram.lightsUniform, new Float32Array([3,1,2,3,4,5]));
```

to

```
gl.uniform1f(shaderProgram.lightsUniform, 3); // I want to send just float 3.0
```

**Summary**: instead of sending array I send just float 3.0.

**Result**: works! lights[0] contains 3.0 (but I sent just float, not an array).

What do I do wrong? How do I pass to shader array of uniforms?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Those answers all use the function `uniform3fv`. `v` as in `vector`.

So you should be using `uniform1fv`, not `uniform1f` for arrays of uniforms.

Comment: I experienced a similar issue. But when I changed to uniform1fv, I got the following console error: Failed to execute 'uniform1fv' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': No function was found that matched the signature provided.

Comment: "check your OpenGL errors before asking questions" This is an inherently challenging space and can be incredibly overwhelming. This is well formed question, with a helpful and direct answer, which is the point of StackOverflow. There's no reason to tell someone they shouldn't ask a question.

Answer (score -3):

**1:** Make sure your **if** statement is within a **function**.

**2:** Make sure **precision** is set **before** declaring uniforms.

```
      #ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
        precision highp float;
      #else
        precision mediump float;
      #endif
      precision mediump int;
```

**3:** Make sure comparison is of correct type:

This will **FAIL**:

```
uniform vec3 neon_whatever;
if(neon_whatever.x == 0){

};
```

This will **FAIL**:

```
uniform vec3 neon_whatever;
if(neon_whatever == 0.0){

};
```

This will **WORK**:

```
uniform vec3 neon_whatever;
if(neon_whatever.x == 0.0){

};
```